# A function that uses a string and string list and returns all the words in the list that are anagrams of the string

Tags: python, string, list, function, python-3.3

I want to define a function find_anagrams_in_word_list(str,str_list) where the parameters should be a string and a list of strings. The value returned should be a list of all the strings in the str_list that are values of str.

I have a simple code that allows you to see if a word is an anagram of a another

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    str1 = sorted(str1)
    str2 = sorted(str2)
    if str1 == str2:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

But i can't seem to understand how to use this for a list.

*edit*

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    str1 = sorted(str1)
    str2 = sorted(str2)
if str1 == str2:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

def find_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,str_list):
    anagrams = []
    for word in str_list:
        if word == str1:
            if (anagram(str1,word)):
                anagrams.append(word)
                print(anagrams)
```

I have gotten this far in creating this code but instead of printing the words if they are anagrams of 'str1' it prints '[]' which i think means that the words in str_list are not being appended to 'anagrams'

I want a output like this

find_anagrams_in_word_list("rat", "[art,tar,gar,jay]")

'art'
'tar'

as they are anagrams of rat.

Comment: so you do `anagram(str1, str)` for every `str` in `str_list`

Comment: Do you know how to write any kind of looping construct in Python? If not, see the tutorial on [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) or [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: @abarnert yes i have done for statements before

Comment: @sc14sd: So, where are you stuck? As Ben says, you want to do something `for` every value in the list. Of course the most obvious thing will just print `True` and `False` a bunch of times, not return a list of strings, so you also have to make `anagram` return something useful, and make your `find_anagrams_in_word_list` do something with those return values, but just try to do the obvious thing first.

Comment: @sc14sd, your function doesn't return True or False, it just prints. First you need to make it to return appropriate value. Then use it in a for loop and call anagram(str1,str2) for every item in the loop. Save the matches in a new list and return that list.

Comment: @sc14sd, I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    str1 = sorted(str1)
    str2 = sorted(str2)
    return str1 == str2 # will be True or False no need for if checks


def find_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,str_list):
    return " ".join([word for word in str_list if anagram(word,str1)]) 

print (find_anagrams_in_word_list("rat", ["art","tar","gar","jay"]))
art tar
```

`if anagram(word,str1)` checks each or in the list against the passed in str1, if `anagram` returns `True` then we keep that word, finally `" ".join` outputs all the words in the list as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
   str1 = sorted(str1)
   str2 = sorted(str2)
   if str1 == str2:
      return True
   else:
      return False

print [i for i in str_list if anagram(str,i)]
```

Here, str is the string to be matched and str_list is the list of all the strings

**EDIT**:

To turn this into a fuction, try this:

```
def anagram(str1,str_list):
    str1 = sorted(str1)
    temp_list=[i for i in str_list if sorted(i)==str1]
    return temp_list
```

Comment: why not just `return str1 == str2`?

Comment: You are right. But I tried to keep his code similar, so he knows the where the problem is.

Comment: The problem wasn't too do with the first code, i had to somehow put this into get_anagram_word_list(str,strlist) to find if words in the list are anagrams of the str, i have gotten further with the code above but it still isn't quite there @padraiccunningham

Answer (score -1):

```
def anagram(my_str,my_list):
    result_list = []
    for item in my_list:
        if item == my_str:
            result_list.append(item)
    return result_list
```

Then you have to assign variables and pass them to your function like this

```
somestr = 's'
somelist = ['s','not s','m','etc','s']
my_anagram = anagram(somestr,somelist)
```

So you will get variable `my_anagram` which contains list of matched elements